# How to create whatsup group in java using whatsApp API or by other way?

Tags: java, whatsapp, whatsapi

I want to create WhatsApp group using java . Does WhatsApp provide any API for this . How should we need to achieve this in java.

Comment: Refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/groups

Comment: "We are announcing the deprecation of Groups through the WhatsApp Business API"

Answer (score 2):

As far as know Whatsapp doesn't provide any official APIs for creating a group.The only functionality available now is the **Click To Chat** feature in which you can send messages to phone numbers without saving them.

More on this at [Whatsapp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251)

If you really want to implement this features there are some work around APIs which is not official and you will have to pay for some of it.

Look at this tutorial [Create Group Using API](https://whatsmate.github.io/2017-04-10-send-whatsapp-group-message-java/)

Comment: Hi luk2302 Sir,                                                                                                                Thank you very much for answer But can we create WhatsApp group using the api provided by you above and start the chat for the same using java API.

Comment: Hi luk2302 Sir,                                                                                                .   The link which you have share above in that only chatting api is there but to create group no api mention in that.

Comment: @GaneshNav I think that making a Whatsapp group with external APIs is a bad practise since they are temporary. For more info [read this post](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-WhatsApp-API-so-that-I-can-integrate-it-with-my-program-to-send-WhatsApp-messages-quickly-automatically)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Could you please suggest the alternate way if possible sir Please .